# Fortran F90 Unclassifiable Statement (Basic)

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I've just started coding in a physics class at my university, so I'm pretty new to all of this. However, I can't find where I'm going wrong on this one:

```
! Purpose: Assignment #2
! Author: Rourke Sekelsky
! Date: 9/7/2015

program arith
implicit none ! Turn off implicit typing
real :: x,y ! Define variables
real, parameter :: pi = 3.14159 ! Set the parameter pi

write(*,*) "Enter x:" ! Prompt user to enter their x-value
read(*,*) x ! Read in x-value

y = (3.0*x)+(6.0*pi)((x**3+x**(7.0/2.0)))+11.0/3.0 
! Determine value of function at given x-value

write(*,*) " f(x) = ",y ! Write out the function value

stop ! Stop execution of program
end program arith
```

EDIT: I'm getting an unclassifiable statement error at the "y = " part. This program won't compile with gfortran, and I'm not sure what's wrong. Some help would be nice, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should describe the intent of the program, its expected output and the current output.

Comment: That would have helped. Woops.

Comment: Therefore, I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-character typo.  You left out the `*` operator between your multiplicands.  `y = (3.0*x)+(6.0*pi)*((x**3.0+x**(7.0/2.0)))+11.0/3.0` works.